# Why is Google Assistant so Slow?

Tags: lineageos, google-assistant

I am using Google Assistant on LineageOS Android 7.1...

Using Assistant is like this:

1. "Ok Google"
2. 1-5 second wait for beep
3. Speak command
4. 5-10 second wait for Google Assistant app
5. 2-5 second wait for analysis to show
6. 5-15 second wait for application launch (such as TuneIn or Pandora)

*Why* is this so *slow*? I'm better off doing it by hand - which should not be. It *should* be like this:

1. "Ok Google"
2. beep
3. Speak command
4. Needed application launches

No waiting, no delays, "it just works."

To add to this - if the display goes to sleep Google Assistant doesnt respond at all, and all attempts to fix seem to assume that Android 7 = Android 7.0 (not 7.1).

I'm using LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2) June 29, 2018 on a Samsung S5.

Comment: Can we assume you are speaking clearly, enunciating sufficiently for understanding, with clear environment around you to eliminate distraction, using the proper phraseology, acceptable to the speech recognition? Have you tried letting someone else repeat your commands on your device, or have they let you try on theirs?

Comment: It understands me fine - but even after recognition, it's slow. It could be in part because the Google Assistant is slow to load up - but beyond that I've no idea why or how to speed it up.